# Phantomjs Não consigo atribuir valor a uma propriedade de um array de objetos

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Estou criando um script que pega links de um site em phantomjs. Minha ideia é armazenar em um vetor o link com o innerHTMl dele e depois preciso modificar o link, porem quando vou modificar posteriormente não consigo.

Meu codigo:

```
var player = 0;
var links = page.evaluate(function() {
                var a = document.querySelectorAll(".link[rel='nofollow']:not(#bg)");
                for(var i =0; i < a.length; i++) {
                    array.push({
                        "html":a[i].innerHTML,
                        "link":a[i].href
                    }
                    );
                }
               return array;
            });

 //Valor não está sendo definido
  links[player]["link"] = 1;
```